# SSH through a proxy?

Tags: ssh, centos, proxy, centos-7

I am trying to connect to a SSH server through a proxy on CentOS 7.

I found some solutions with `ProxyCommand` and `connect-proxy` but this one is not available for CentOS 7.

I found another way with `nc` (`nmap-ncat`) and the `-X` option but the one installed on CentOS 7 returns an error `nc: invalid option -- 'X'`.

How can I connect to a SSH server through a proxy with CentOS 7?

Comment: What kind of Proxy ?

Comment: Company proxy, common one.

Comment: Go find out what type of proxy it is, advise the specifics of your usage case  then someone can answer your question.  If its an HTTP[s] proxy  and port 22 is blocked, the answer is very different to (for example) to a SOX proxy.  Both proxies are common.

Comment: Sorry, it is a HTTP proxy, the port 22 is not blocked (I guess). I could set up the server to another port to try.

Comment: If port 22 is not blocked, why do you need a proxy?

Comment: Because I cannot access to outside/internet without the proxy. (for everything). The solution I gave is working for ubuntu but not for Centos 7 in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have encountered this problem on a Centos 7 myself. In order to connect I installed `proxy-connect` that is available on the `epel` repos.

Then, once installed, is was just a matter of finding the proper options for my case, a SOCKS5 proxy:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect-proxy -S proxy_ip:proxy_port %h %p" remote_user@remote_server_ip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If using an HTTP proxy, you just need to use -H instead of -S
(the rest is identical)

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7, which probably has ncat version 6.x installed (check with `rpm -q nmap-ncat`, the options are very different from ncat version 7.x.

For the nc command, instead of `nc -X connect -x <proxy:port> %h %p`, you need to use `nc --proxy <proxy:port> %h %p`

The rest is the same.

For testing, sshmyip.com is a useful site.