# SSH'ing through a proxy with CentOS 8

Tags: ssh, centos, proxy, netcat, centos-8

I'm using CentOS 8, and I'm trying to SSH from behind a firewall through a (HTTP but also somehow SOCKS) proxy.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616021/1593077), which suggests using `nc -X` - but my `nc` doesn't support that. I've read comments, and the nearly-duplicate question:

[SSH through a proxy?](https://superuser.com/questions/1140647/ssh-through-a-proxy)

and those say I should be able to install connect-proxy. But - I can't! Or at least - I don't know which repository I can add which has it. Currently, my repositories are:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/AppStream/$basearch/os/
http://mirror.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/cr/$basearch/os/
http://debuginfo.centos.org/$releasever/$basearch/
http://mirror.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/extras/$basearch/os/
file:///run/media/CentOS/BaseOS
file:///run/media/CentOS/AppStream
http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/Source/
http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/AppStream/Source/
http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/extras/Source/
http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/centosplus/Source/
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel8/x86_64
https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/leigh123linux/cinnamon_el8/
http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/stenstorp/MATE/epel-8-$basearch/
```

Answer (score 1):

`socat` is a part of CentOS 8 installation tree and seems to support HTTP proxy and CONNECT method and for sure supports SOCKS proxies as well. This is in fact what I use, both to get through the proxy at my workplace or to connect to hidden services on TOR network. I use the following ProxyCommand for SOCKS:

```
ProxyCommand socat STDIO SOCKS4A:<socks proxy name or IP>:%h:%p[,socksport=<socks port if not 1080>]
```

Look for `PROXY:` in socat man page for HTTP proxy.